# An error in deployed app (Vercel): MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User"

Tags: mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema, vercel

In my Next.js app, I have a component that contains the following conditional rendering

```
    {session ? (
                <UserFeedback
                    ratings={ratings}
                    comments={blogComments}
                    blog_id={_id}
                />
            ) : (
                <div className="my-8">
                    <p className="text-2xl font-semibold text-center mb-4">
                        Must be signed in to give feedback
                    </p>
                    <button
                        className={`flex flex-row gap-2 items-center mx-auto px-4 py-2 font-semibold rounded bg-emerald-500 hover:bg-emerald-600 active:bg-emerald-700`}
                        onClick={() => signIn("google")}
                    >
                        <span>Sign in</span>

                        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">login</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            )}
```

In development, it works as intended where the UserFeedback component is rendered when a user is currrently signed in. I deployed the app in vercel and has been getting the following error whenever I try to visit the page that is supposed to render the UserFeedback component.

error in deployment: Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information).

The log shows the following error: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".

UserFeedback Component

```
"use client";

import { useState, useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { DarkModeContext } from "@/contexts/DarkModeContext";
import { UserContext } from "@/contexts/UserContext";
import Image from "next/image";

function UserFeedback({ ratings, comments, blog_id }) {
    const { liked_by, disliked_by } = ratings;

    const { darkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

    const [blogComments, setBlogComments] = useState(comments);
    const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
    const [likedBy, setLikedBy] = useState(liked_by);
    const [dislikedBy, setDislikedBy] = useState(disliked_by);
    const [formVisible, setFormVisible] = useState(false);

    const textareaRef = useRef(null);

    const rateBlogHandle = async (action) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`/api/blogs/blog/rate-action`, {
                method: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    blog_id: blog_id,
                    user_id: user?._id,
                    action: action,
                    liked_by: likedBy,
                    disliked_by: dislikedBy,
                }),
            });
            if (res.ok) {
                const data = await res.json();
                const ratings = data.updatedBlog.ratings;
                setLikedBy(ratings.liked_by);
                setDislikedBy(ratings.disliked_by);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    const commentHandle = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(`/api/blogs/blog/comment-action`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    blog_id: blog_id,
                    user_id: user?._id,
                    comment: comment,
                }),
            });
            if (res.ok) {
                const data = await res.json();
                setBlogComments(data.newComments);
                setComment("");
                textareaRef.current.value = "";
            } else {
                const data = await res.json();
                window.alert(data.message);
                setComment("");
                textareaRef.current.value = "";
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-2 items-center py-4">
                <button
                    onClick={() => setFormVisible((prevState) => !prevState)}
                    className={`${
                        user === null ? "pointer-events-none" : ""
                    } p-4 rounded flex flex-row gap-2 items-center text-neutral-50 bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-600 active:bg-sky-700`}
                >
                    <span>Add Comment</span>

                    <span className="material-symbols-outlined">add</span>
                </button>
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                    <button
                        className={`${
                            user === null ? "pointer-events-none" : ""
                        } p-4 rounded flex flex-row gap-2 items-center text-neutral-50 bg-emerald-500 hover:bg-emerald-600 active:bg-emerald-700`}
                        disabled={user === null}
                        onClick={() => rateBlogHandle("LIKE")}
                    >
                        <span>Like</span>

                        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">thumb_up</span>
                    </button>
                    <button
                        className={`${
                            user === null ? "pointer-events-none" : ""
                        } p-4 rounded flex flex-row gap-2 items-center text-neutral-50 bg-rose-500 hover:bg-rose-600 active:bg-rose-700`}
                        disabled={user === null}
                        onClick={() => rateBlogHandle("DISLIKE")}
                    >
                        <span>Dislike</span>

                        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">thumb_down</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center">
                    <span
                        className={`p-4 rounded ${
                            darkMode ? "bg-zinc-900" : "bg-neutral-700 text-neutral-50"
                        }`}
                    >
                        Likes: {likedBy.length}
                    </span>
                    <span
                        className={`p-4 rounded ${
                            darkMode ? "bg-zinc-900" : "bg-neutral-700 text-neutral-50"
                        }`}
                    >
                        Dislikes: {dislikedBy.length}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form
                className={`${formVisible ? "block" : "hidden"}`}
                onSubmit={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    commentHandle();
                }}
            >
                <textarea
                    ref={textareaRef}
                    required
                    maxLength={420}
                    className={`resize-none w-full outline-emerald-500 rounded h-64 ${
                        darkMode ? "bg-zinc-900" : "bg-neutral-200"
                    } p-4`}
                    onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button
                    className={`py-2 px-4 ${
                        darkMode
                            ? "bg-zinc-900 hover:text-emerald-500 active:text-emerald-600"
                            : "bg-emerald-500 text-neutral-50 hover:bg-emerald-600 active:bg-emerald-700"
                    } ${
                        user === null ? "pointer-events-none" : ""
                    } ml-auto flex flex-row gap-2 items-center rounded mt-2`}
                    type="submit"
                >
                    <span>Comment</span>
                    <span className="material-symbols-outlined">send</span>
                </button>
            </form>
            <hr className="my-4" />
            <div>
                {blogComments.map((commentObj) => {
                    const { _id, comment, comment_by } = commentObj;
                    const { name, profile_pic } = comment_by;
                    return (
                        <div
                            key={_id}
                            className={`${
                                darkMode ? "bg-zinc-900" : "bg-neutral-200"
                            } py-4 px-2 my-4`}
                        >
                            <div className="flex flex-row gap-2 items-center mb-2">
                                <Image
                                    src={profile_pic?.img_src}
                                    alt={profile_pic?.img_alt}
                                    height={120}
                                    width={120}
                                    className="block w-8 h-8 rounded-full"
                                />

                                <p className="font-bold">{name}</p>
                            </div>

                            <p className="">{comment}</p>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UserFeedback;
```

UserContext

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null);

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Basically the page that I'm trying to visit should render everything aside from the UserFeedback component unless a user is currently signed in, but instead it keeps throwing an error even though it is working as intended in development.

There is a specific situation where it would work as intended, I would need to sign in and visit the profile page before visiting the page that is supposed to render the UserFeedback component.